# Can't filter nodes on cypher query Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I've got some data, like the following:

```
(:Artist {id: 1, name: "Depeche Mode"})<-[:PLAYED_BY]-(:Song {id: 1, title: "Enjoy The Silence"})-[:PLAYED_BY]->(:Artist {id: 2, name: "Lacuna Coil"})
```

I will need to query, for example, for all the `Song` that are `PLAYED_BY` Artist with `id` 1 and 2.

I was thinking about something like:

```
MATCH (s:Song)-[:PLAYED_BY]->(a:Artist)
WHERE a.id IN [1, 2]
RETURN s
```

But this one is not working as I want: because it's like an `OR`, and I would like to use it like an `AND`.

Any suggestions?

EDIT1: The number of `Artist` should be arbitrary.

EDIT2: I will also need to run this query using a full text index, like this:

```
START song=node:node_auto_index("title:*enjo*") 
MATCH ... 
RETURN ...
```

That song is also played by other artists, for example `Song 1`, played by `Artist [1, 2, 3]`.
When I query for `[1,2]` it should be returned anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to find Songs that are played by both Artist 1 and Artist 2?

How about this query:

```
MATCH (a1:Artist)<-[:PLAYED_BY]-(s:Song)-[:PLAYED_BY]->(a2:Artist)
WHERE a1.id = 1 AND a2.id = 2
RETURN s
```

**Edit**

For an arbitrary number of Artists:

```
WITH [1,2] AS ids
MATCH (a:Artist)<-[:PLAYED_BY]-(s:Song)
WITH collect(a.id) AS artistIds, ids,s
WHERE all(x IN artistIds WHERE x IN ids) AND all(x IN ids WHERE x IN artistIds)
RETURN s
```

Collect the ids of all artists that have played the song then use the Cypher collection predicate function `all` to filter on only the desired Artist ids.

The array `[1,2]` can be parameterized like this: `WITH {id_array} AS ids ...`

**Edit**

Using a legacy index for fuzzy text search should work with this approach. Just replace the unbound `(s:Song)` piece of the pattern in the MATCH with the bound `song` variable populated by the legacy index:

```
START song=node:node_auto_index("title:*enjo*")
WITH [1,2] AS ids, song
MATCH (a:Artist)<-[:PLAYED_BY]-(song)
WITH collect(a.id) AS artistIds, ids, song
WHERE all(x IN artistIds WHERE x IN ids) AND all(x IN ids WHERE x IN artistIds)
RETURN s
```

Comment: Updated answer to handle an arbitrary number of artists.

Comment: This solution actually works. Meanwhile I've add a legacy index, because I will need to do this even with a partial title song. For example: `START song=node:node_auto_index("title:*enjo*") MATCH ... RETURN ...`. When I try to apply your solution to this kind of query, it doesn't work for me...

Comment: @karnaugh this approach should work with a legacy index as well. Try the example in the most recent edit above. Does this work?

Comment: @william-lion it partially works. I mean, this one is really exclusive. I.E. many Artists made their own cover of Enjoy The Silence, so for that song, i will have more then 2 Artist nodes linked to it. This query will return the Enjoy The Silence node if that node is linked only to the Artists in my custom list (i.e. [1,2]). My goal is to return songs that at least are connected to Artists in my custom list. Maybe my question was really bad explained...

Answer (score 2):

This should work for your example:

```
MATCH (a1:Artist)<-[:PLAYED_BY]-(s:Song)-[:PLAYED_BY]->(a2:Artist)
WHERE a1.id = 1 AND a2.id = 2
RETURN s
```